# How to fix choppy (but fast) OpenGL on Intel gfx card on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: graphics-card, performance, ubuntu-9.10, intel-graphics, opengl

I have just installed Ubuntu 9.10 on my laptop with an i915 Intel integrated graphics, and OpenGL is now extremely choppy. However, the overall performance is better. On 9.04, I got ~800 FPS on glxgears. Now I get ~3000 FPS!

I only have this problem with Compiz enabled. However, Compiz itself is not choppy at all (and it uses OpenGL).

Everything was working fine on 9.04 with UXA/DRI2 enabled.

Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: could the choppyness be a 'tearing effect'? If so (I am just grasping at ideas here) could be vertical sync needs to be enabled?

Comment: @Jakub: No, I don't think so. It was stuttering, not tearing. However, it doesn't seems to happen any more. An update must have fixed it. It works fine with Compiz now, but KWin still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable Visual Effects. It's probably not what you want to hear, but it works.

Comment: Well, I don't like that solution, but I'm using it for now. I would be very happy if somebody had a proper solution...